# appointment release/lock control in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetimepicker

I've taken xdsoft datetimepicker as my framework to program appointment system. My basic idea is taking all the configuration parameters and appointments from sql database, so far it works great but the problem is still the flexibility, if I for example want only to allow specific times for a specific day, it is always being applied to all days and not just a specific day. If I want to disable specific time, it's always being disabled for all days as well. What I configured so far is that I calculate everything in PHP and echo all the options straight in datetimepicker ini. That's my code:

```
<?php
echo'
    <script> //conf calendar
                        var reserviert = $.parseJSON(\''.$reserved.'\'); //here in this var I get all appointments from sql as a json and parse it afterwards
                        window.onerror = function(errorMsg) {$("#console").html($("#console").html()+"<br>"+errorMsg)}
                        $.datetimepicker.setLocale("de");
                        var logik = function( currentDateTime ){  //logic for specific weekdays
                            switch(currentDateTime.getDay()){
                                case 1:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min1'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max1'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow1'].'] 
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 2:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min2'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max2'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow2'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 3:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min3'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max3'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow3'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 4:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min4'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max4'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow4'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 5:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min5'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max5'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow5'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 6:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min6'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max6'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow6'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                case 7:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                      minTime: '.$confIn['min7'].',
                                      maxTime: '.$confIn['max7'].',
                                      allowTimes: ['.$confIn['allow7'].']
                                    });
                                break;
                                default:
                                    this.setOptions({
                                         minTime: false,
                                         maxTime: false,
                                         allowTimes: []
                                    });
                            }
                        };

                        $("#datetimepicker3").datetimepicker({
                            '.$blocked.' //blocking weekened
                            inline:true,
                            value: new Date(),
                            allowTimes:['.$weekdatetimeconf['onlyT'].$timeFlex.'], //allowing times, general + flex conf, i should do it in one variable, still need to change it though
                            allowDates: ['.$weekdatetimeconf['onlyD'].$dateFlex.'], // lockes everything except specific date
                            disabledDates: ['.$weekdatetimeconf['banD'].'], // lock specific date
                            disabledWeekDays:['.$weekdatetimeconf['banweekdays'].'], //lock specific weekdays
                            step: '.$allg[0]['terminspanne'].', // min
                            todayButton: true,
                            yearStart: "'.date("Y").'",
                            yearEnd: "'.date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')).'",
                            dayOfWeekStart: 1,
                            onChangeDateTime: logik,
                            onShow: logik,
                            onSelectTime(dp,$input){ //still under construction
                                if($.inArray($input.val(), reserviert)){
                                    alert("reserved!");
                                }
                            },
                            minDate: "0",
                            maxDate: "'.date("Y/m/d", maxDate($freigabe)).'",
                            minTime: "'.date("H:i", strtotime($allg[0]['minOeffnungszeit'])).'",
                            maxTime: "'.date("H:i", strtotime($allg[0]['maxOeffnungszeit'])).'",


    });</script>';</php>
```

so far the ini, I'm still asking myself if there is some kind of better solution for managing free/locked times in the datetimepicker because mine has too many bugs which needs to be fixed. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the most flexible solution but still a good approach for solving the issue with locking the times at specific dates in JQuery

```
<script>
var specificDates = []; 
var hoursToTakeAway = [];
var i=0; var old=0; var from; var collect=[]; var changed = false; var bag=[];
                    $.each( reserviert, function(key, value){
                        specificDates.push(moment(key).format("DD/MM/YYYY")); 
                        $.each( value, function( keyn, valuen ){
                            if(i !== old){
                                old=i;
                                changed = true;
                            }
                            if(i == old){
                                if(keyn.indexOf("from") >= 0){
                                    from = valuen;
                                } else{
                                    bag = addBetween(parseInt(from), parseInt(valuen));
                                    if(changed == false){
                                        collect = bag.concat(collect);  
                                    } else collect = bag;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        hoursToTakeAway.push(collect);
                        i++;        
                    });
                    function addBetween(p1, p2){
                        var hoursToAdd=[];
                        for(var i=p1; i<=p2; i++){
                            hoursToAdd.push(i);
                        }
                        return hoursToAdd;
                    }
</script>
```

the code is placed between var reserviert and window.onerror and iterates over the object reserviert which has date as key and times as values. It is being saved in the arrays specificDates and hoursToTakeAway. I lock the times which I got from array

```
<?php 
    echo '$("#datetimepicker3").datetimepicker({
                                        onGenerate:function(ct,$i){
                                            var ind = specificDates.indexOf(moment(ct).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
                                            $(".xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time").show();
                                            if(ind !== -1){
                                                $(".xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time").each(function(index){
                                                    if(hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf($(this).text()) !== -1) {
                                                        $(this).hide();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            '.$blocked.'
                                        },
                                        inline:true,
                                        value: new Date(), //(alloweDateRe)(regexdates)
                                        allowTimes:['.$weekdatetimeconf['onlyT'].$timeFlex.'], 
                                        allowDates: ['.$weekdatetimeconf['onlyD'].$dateFlex.'], 
                                        disabledDates: ['.$weekdatetimeconf['banD'].'], 
                                        disabledWeekDays:['.$weekdatetimeconf['banweekdays'].'], 
                                        step: '.$allg[0]['terminspanne'].', // min
                                        todayButton: true,
                                        yearStart: "'.date("Y").'",
                                        yearEnd: "'.date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')).'",
                                        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
                                        onChangeDateTime: logik,
                                        onShow: logik,
                                        minDate: "0",
                                        maxDate: "'.date("Y/m/d", maxDate($freigabe)).'",
                                        minTime: "'.date("H:i", strtotime($allg[0]['minOeffnungszeit'])).'",
                                        maxTime: "'.date("H:i", strtotime($allg[0]['maxOeffnungszeit'])).'"
                                    });'; 
?>
```